# Bootstrap template allows text to overlay photo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with using a bootstrap template for mobile...

[image: This is what the section looks like on mobile, rather than degrading nicely..]

I **never** want the text to overlay over an image, however I can't seem to find any straight answer on how to avoid it happening.

Here is the code currently:

```
<div class="banner-bottom" id="photos">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bottom-grids">
            <div class="col-md-3 bottom-grid">
                <img src="images/bed.jpg" height="200px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 bottom-grid">
                <p><b>Philosophy:</b><br> We believe meaningful activities provide an atmosphere of good health and spiritual well-being. The activity program is designed to offer opportunities for friendship and self-worth.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 bottom-grid">
                <img src="images/entry.jpg" height="200px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 bottom-grid">
                <p><b>Location:</b><br>Located just minutes from downtown Sacramento. Near the Jefferson Boulevard & West Capital Avenue intersection. Close to shopping, churches and senior centers.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is nothing tricky in the CSS -- typical bootstrap 25% width for col-md-3.

```
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
```

How can I make my text areas well defined enough so they don't overlay my images?  I would assume setting each div as col-md-3 with a 25% width would be enough to avoid this issue, but I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Could you please post a plunker? Would be much easier to debug

Comment: What formatting does `bottom-grids` class apply? Why are you not using the `row` class around your columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `col-**` classes only inside `row` class elements. `col-**` classes are floated items and `row` class has all needed `clearfix` styles and negative margins. Something like this:

```
<div class="banner-bottom" id="photos">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row bottom-grids">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 bottom-grid">
            <img src="images/bed.jpg" height="200px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 bottom-grid">
            <p><b>Philosophy:</b><br> We believe meaningful activities provide an atmosphere of good health and spiritual well-being. The activity program is designed to offer opportunities for friendship and self-worth.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 bottom-grid">
            <img src="images/entry.jpg" height="200px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 bottom-grid">
            <p><b>Location:</b><br>Located just minutes from downtown Sacramento. Near the Jefferson Boulevard & West Capital Avenue intersection. Close to shopping, churches and senior centers.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, bootstrap does lots of work for you and I'm sure you do not need those `.bottom-grid` classes and `class="clearfix"` `div` over there. Keep it as much simple as you can and you will see you markup improving.

One more thing is giving your `img` elements `max-width: 100%; height: auto;`, cause now they are overlapping their parent `col-` containers.

Answer (score 2):

Try making use of "row" class and for smaller screen use "col-sm-*" based on your need to display.

This is just a sample edit to help you start with something:

```
<div class="banner-bottom" id="photos">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row bottom-grids">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 bottom-grid">
            <img src="images/bed.jpg" height="200px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 bottom-grid">
            <p><b>Philosophy:</b><br> We believe meaningful activities provide an atmosphere of good health and spiritual well-being. The activity program is designed to offer opportunities for friendship and self-worth.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 bottom-grid">
            <img src="images/entry.jpg" height="200px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 bottom-grid">
            <p><b>Location:</b><br>Located just minutes from downtown Sacramento. Near the Jefferson Boulevard & West Capital Avenue intersection. Close to shopping, churches and senior centers.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do add `class="img-responsive"` to `img` tag as below

Do not set height to `img` tag.

```
<div class="banner-bottom" id="photos">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bottom-grids">
            <div class="col-md-3 bottom-grid">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/bed.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 bottom-grid">
                <p><b>Philosophy:</b><br> We believe meaningful activities provide an atmosphere of good health and spiritual well-being. The activity program is designed to offer opportunities for friendship and self-worth.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 bottom-grid">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/entry.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 bottom-grid">
                <p><b>Location:</b><br>Located just minutes from downtown Sacramento. Near the Jefferson Boulevard & West Capital Avenue intersection. Close to shopping, churches and senior centers.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```